# Remove double quotes within the string that has double quotes in R

Tags: r

I am working on movies dataset from Kaggle and I am trying to parse the Stringified JSON columns.

I encountered an issue when I tried to parse the code,

For example, The value of one of the fields is:  "Sgt. Jeffrey "Jeff" Rabin"

Here is the detail of the error

[image]

How can I remove the quotes and make it appear like this: "Sgt. Jeffrey Jeff Rabin" using gsub in R?

Comment: Can you provide first few rows of your data using `dput` ? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 . Do you need `gsub('"', '', 'Sgt. Jeffrey "Jeff" Rabin')` ?

Comment: Your JSON source is broken.  You should fix the JSON there and then reimport into R.

Comment: How to fix the JSON?

Comment: I cant really paste the rows here because the characters are too long to fit in this box.